# What integration test framework has the best docker support?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, testing, integration

We need integration testing framework - pass a url pass requests to that url and get responses and evaluate repsonses.

Requirements:

```
1. We want a tool that can easily implement into a CICD pipeline like Jenkins/hudson
2. Not to heavy of a footprint
3. Ease of writing tests
4. love to be able to give a docker image and some files however the tests are built and integrate that
```

Need to be able to do insertions if they return data or not
Support decent sized files

Comment: hi, @demisheep, not sure whether you mean you are going to test RESTful APIs? In terms of that, there is not so much specific compated to a non-docker deployment, imo. Some Java test frameworks have introduces annotations to instantiate containers. Nice semantics to write API tests could be found with Python Requests library. See: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/a-systematic-way-to-test-restful-apis-with-curl/2614#2614

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?